# Using boost::iostreams::tee_device?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, boost-iostreams

Can someone help me?

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/tee.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <sstream>  
#include <cassert>  

namespace io = boost::iostreams;
typedef io::stream<io::tee_device<std::stringstream, std::stringstream> > Tee;
std::stringstream ss1, ss2;
Tee my_split(ss1, ss2); // redirects to both streams
my_split << "Testing";
assert(ss1.str() == "Testing" && ss1.str() == ss2.str());
```

But it won't compile in VC9:

```
c:\lib\boost_current_version\boost\iostreams\stream.hpp(131) : error C2665: 'boost::iostreams::tee_device<Sink1,Sink2>::tee_device' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Has anyone gotten this to work? I know I could make my own class to do it, but I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use the [constructor-forwarding version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream_forwarding_constructors) of `io::stream`, which construct a tee-stream itself and forward all arguments to that. C++03 has only limited capabilities when it comes to forwarding arguments to functions (amount of overloads needed easily grow exponentially). It (`io::stream`) makes the following restrictions:

> Each of these members constructs an instance of stream and associates it with an instance of the Device T constructed from the given lists of arguments. *The T constructors involved must take all arguments by value or const reference.*

Well, but the `tee_device` constructor says

> Constructs an instance of tee_device based on the given pair of Sinks. Each function parameter is a non-const reference if the corresponding template argument is a stream or stream buffer type, and a const reference otherwise.

That won't work, of course. `io::stream` provides another constructor that takes a `T` as first argument. This works here (Compiles, at least. The assertion fails, though. I've not worked with `boost::iostreams` so i can't help with that)

```
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
typedef io::tee_device<std::stringstream, std::stringstream> TeeDevice;
typedef io::stream< TeeDevice > TeeStream;
std::stringstream ss1, ss2;
TeeDevice my_tee(ss1, ss2); 
TeeStream my_split(my_tee);
my_split << "Testing";
assert(ss1.str() == "Testing" && ss1.str() == ss2.str());
```

Edit: After calling `flush()` or streaming `<< std::flush`, the assertion passes.

Comment: Wow... did not see that in the documentation. Awesome work, thanks a lot!

Comment: Correct analysis of problem although there is a more terse solution in the form of `std::ref`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to set it up like this:

```
typedef io::tee_device<std::stringstream, std::stringstream> Tee;
typedef io::stream<Tee> TeeStream;

std::stringstream ss1, ss2;
Tee my_tee(ss1, ss2);
TeeStream my_split(my_tee);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::ref` to pass non-copyable sinks.

```
Tee my_split(std::ref(ss1), std::ref(ss2));
```