# C++ "hello world" Boost tee example program

Tags: c++, boost-iostreams

The Boost C++ library has [Function Template tee](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/tee.html)

> The class templates tee_filter and tee_device provide two ways to split an output sequence
>   so that all data is directed simultaneously to two different locations.

I am looking for a complete C++ example using Boost tee to output to standard out and to a file like "sample.txt".

Comment: What do you mean by boost tee?

Comment: [Previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670465/using-boostiostreamsteedevice) (not exactly a dupe) has an example.

Comment: tee is one of the libraries in boost

Comment: Any links? I can't find anything related .. maybe it's just me

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/tee.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on help from the question John linked:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/tee.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::cout;

namespace bio = boost::iostreams;
using bio::tee_device;
using bio::stream;

int main()
{
    typedef tee_device<ostream, ofstream> TeeDevice;
    typedef stream<TeeDevice> TeeStream;
    ofstream ofs("sample.txt");
    TeeDevice my_tee(cout, ofs); 
    TeeStream my_split(my_tee);
    my_split << "Hello, World!\n";
    my_split.flush();
    my_split.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `tee_filter` I'm currently using to tee my Boost.Test output:

```
{ // init code, use static streams to keep them alive until test run process end

    using namespace boost::iostreams;
    static ofstream ofs("boost_test_output.log.xml"); // log file
    static tee_filter<ostream>  fileFilt(ofs); // tee all passed data to logfile

    // note derives from `boost::iostreams::output_filter`
    static text_xml_readability_filter xmlFilt; // filter all passed data, making the XML output readable

    static filtering_ostream filter; // master filter

    filter.push(fileFilt); // 1st, tee off any data to the file (raw boost XML)
    filter.push(xmlFilt);  // 2nd make the xml data stream readable (linebreaks, etc.)
    filter.push(cout);     // 3rd output the readable XML to cout

    boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.set_stream( filter );
}
```