# C++ Output UTF-8 strings as UTF-16 to std::cout

Tags: c++, windows, boost, unicode, encoding

I have a lot of code written based on UTF-8 using C++03, STL and Boost 1.54.
All the code outputs data to the console via `std::cout` or `std::cerr`.
I do not want to introduce a new library to my code base or switch to C++11,
but I want to port the code to Windows. 
Rewriting all code to either use `std::wcout` or `std::wcerr` instead of
`std::cout` or `std::cerr` is not what I intend but I still want to display
all on console as UTF-16.
Is there a way to change `std::cout` and `std::cerr` to transform all char based data (which is UTF-8 encoded) to wchar_t based data (which would be UTF-16 encoded) before writing it to the console?
It would be great to see a solution for this using just C++03, STL and Boost 1.54.
I found that Boost Locale has conversion functions for single strings and there is a UTF-8 to UTF-32 iterator in Boost Spirit available but I could not find any facet codecvt to transform UTF-8 to UTF-16 without using an additional library or switching to C++11.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know it is doable with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9774569/4118553), but I hope to find a better solution here.

Comment: Stdin/out are stuck with 8-bit encodings due to I/O redirection.  Switch the console to utf-8 instead, call SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8) in your main() function.  No rewrite of your code required.  Update the font as well, the default Terminal font is no longer appropriate, Consolas or Lucida Sans are the usual choice.

Comment: I am sure there is some way to work around the 8-bit encoding problem. I am aware that you can set the output console to UTF-8 on Windows, but this is not my aim. I want to get a proper UTF-16 output for Windows.

Comment: You won't get UTF-16 output on the console though, because everything written to the console is interpreted somehow - unless you use the Console API directly and don't go through `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not came up with a better solution than already hinted.
So I will just share the solution based on streambuf here for anyone who is interested in it.
Hopefully, someone will come up with a better solution and share it here.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_UNICODE) && (defined(__MSVCRT__) ||defined(_MSC_VER))
#define TEST_ARG_TYPE wchar_t
#else /* not windows, unicode */
#define TEST_ARG_TYPE char
#endif /* windows, unicode */


#ifndef _O_U16TEXT
#define _O_U16TEXT 0x20000
#endif


static size_t countValidUtf8Bytes(const unsigned char * buf, const size_t size) {
    size_t i, charSize;
    const unsigned char * src = buf;
    for (i = 0; i < size && (*src) != 0; i += charSize, src += charSize) {
        charSize = 0;
        if ((*src) >= 0xFC) {
            charSize = 6;
        } else if ((*src) >= 0xF8) {
            charSize = 5;
        } else if ((*src) >= 0xF0) {
            charSize = 4;
        } else if ((*src) >= 0xE0) {
            charSize = 3;
        } else if ((*src) >= 0xC0) {
            charSize = 2;
        } else if ((*src) >= 0x80) {
            /* Skip continuous UTF-8 character (should never happen). */
            for (; (i + charSize) < size && src[charSize] != 0 && src[charSize] >= 0x80; charSize++) {
                charSize++;
            }
        } else {
            /* ASCII character. */
            charSize = 1;
        }
        if ((i + charSize) > size) break;
    }
    return i;
}


#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_UNICODE) && (defined(__MSVCRT__) ||defined(_MSC_VER))
#include <locale>
#include <streambuf>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

extern "C" {
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <windows.h>

int _CRT_glob;
extern void __wgetmainargs(int *, wchar_t ***, wchar_t ***, int, int *);
}


class Utf8ToUtf16Buffer : public std::basic_streambuf< char, std::char_traits<char> > {
private:
    char * outBuf;
    FILE * outFd;
public:
    static const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    typedef std::char_traits<char> traits_type;
    typedef traits_type::int_type int_type;
    typedef traits_type::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef traits_type::off_type off_type;

    explicit Utf8ToUtf16Buffer(FILE * o) : outBuf(new char[BUFFER_SIZE]), outFd(o) {
        /* Initialize the put pointer. Overflow won't get called until this
         * buffer is filled up, so we need to use valid pointers.
         */
        this->setp(outBuf, outBuf + BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
    }

    ~Utf8ToUtf16Buffer() {
        delete[] outBuf;
    }
protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c);
    virtual int_type sync();
};


Utf8ToUtf16Buffer::int_type Utf8ToUtf16Buffer::overflow(Utf8ToUtf16Buffer::int_type c) {
    char * iBegin = this->outBuf;
    char * iEnd = this->pptr();
    int_type result = traits_type::not_eof(c);

    /* If this is the end, add an eof character to the buffer.
     * This is why the pointers passed to setp are off by 1
     * (to reserve room for this).
     */
    if ( ! traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof()) ) {
        *iEnd = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
        iEnd++;
    }

    /* Calculate output data length. */
    int_type iLen = static_cast<int_type>(iEnd - iBegin);
    int_type iLenU8 = static_cast<int_type>(
        countValidUtf8Bytes(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(iBegin), static_cast<size_t>(iLen))
    );

    /* Convert string to UTF-16 and write to defined file descriptor. */
    if (fwprintf(this->outFd, boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(std::string(outBuf, outBuf + iLenU8)).c_str()) < 0) {
        /* Failed to write data to output file descriptor. */
        result = traits_type::eof();
    }

    /* Reset the put pointers to indicate that the buffer is free. */
    if (iLenU8 == iLen) {
        this->setp(outBuf, outBuf + BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
    } else {
        /* Move incomplete UTF-8 characters remaining in buffer. */
        const size_t overhead = static_cast<size_t>(iLen - iLenU8);
        memmove(outBuf, outBuf + iLenU8, overhead);
        this->setp(outBuf + overhead, outBuf + BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
    }

    return result;
}


Utf8ToUtf16Buffer::int_type Utf8ToUtf16Buffer::sync() {
    return traits_type::eq_int_type(this->overflow(traits_type::eof()), traits_type::eof()) ? -1 : 0;
}

#endif /* windows, unicode */


int test_main(int argc, TEST_ARG_TYPE ** argv);


#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_UNICODE) && (defined(__MSVCRT__) ||defined(_MSC_VER))
int main(/*int argc, char ** argv*/) {
    wchar_t ** wenpv, ** wargv;
    int wargc, si = 0;
    /* this also creates the global variable __wargv */
    __wgetmainargs(&wargc, &wargv, &wenpv, _CRT_glob, &si);
    /* enable UTF-16 output to standard output console */
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::locale::global(boost::locale::generator().generate("UTF-8"));
    Utf8ToUtf16Buffer u8cout(stdout);
    std::streambuf * out = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::cout.rdbuf(&u8cout);
    /* process user defined main function */
    const int result = test_main(wargc, wargv);
    /* revert stream buffers to let cout clean up remaining memory correctly */
    std::cout.rdbuf(out);
    return result;
#else /* not windows or unicode */
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    return test_main(argc, argv);
#endif /* windows, unicode */
}

int test_main(int /*argc*/, TEST_ARG_TYPE ** /*argv*/) {
    const std::string str("\x61\x62\x63\xC3\xA4\xC3\xB6\xC3\xBC\xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x88\xE3\x81\x84\xE3\x82\xA2\xE3\x82\xA8\xE3\x82\xA4\xE4\xBA\x9C\xE6\xB1\x9F\xE6\x84\x8F");

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= str.size(); i++) {
        const std::string part(str.begin(), str.begin() + i);
        const size_t validByteCount = countValidUtf8Bytes(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(part.c_str()), part.size());
        wprintf(L"i = %u, v = %u\n", i, validByteCount);
        const std::string valid(str.begin(), str.begin() + validByteCount);
        std::cout << valid << std::endl;
        std::cout.flush();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < part.size(); j++) {
            wprintf(L"%02X", static_cast<int>(part[j]) & 0xFF);
        }
        wprintf(L"\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel like this is probably a bad idea.. but I think it should still be seen as it does work provided that the console has the right font..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
//#include <io.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>

std::wstring UTF8ToUTF16(const char* utf8)
{
    std::wstring utf16;
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8, -1, NULL, 0);
    if (len > 1)
    {
        utf16.resize(len);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8, -1, &utf16[0], len);
    }
    return utf16;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const char* data)
{
    //_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    SetConsoleCP(1200);
    std::wstring str = UTF8ToUTF16(data);
    DWORD slen = str.size();
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str.c_str(), slen, &slen, nullptr);

    MessageBoxW(NULL, str.c_str(), L"", 0);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::string& data)
{
    //_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    SetConsoleCP(1200);
    std::wstring str = UTF8ToUTF16(&data[0]);
    DWORD slen = str.size();
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str.c_str(), slen, &slen, nullptr);
    return os;
}

std::wostream& operator <<(std::wostream& os, const wchar_t* data)
{
    DWORD slen = wcslen(data);
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), data, slen, &slen, nullptr);
    return os;
}

std::wostream& operator <<(std::wostream& os, const std::wstring& data)
{
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), data.c_str(), data.size(), nullptr, nullptr);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Россия";
}
```

And now `cout` and `std::wcout` both use the `WriteConsoleW` function.. You'd have to overload it for `const char*, char*, std::string, char`, etc.. whatever you need.. Maybe template it.

Comment: So, now you have a handful of ambiguous overloads for `operator<<`. What do. I think the linked approach with a custom streambuf would already be superior. And more performant as it allows buffering individual insertions.

Comment: I agree with sehe. This solution does not look better than the streambuf approach. I was looking for a little bit better way as you need to handle not just the mentioned but a far wider range of overloads, too...