# Redirect the copy of std::cout to the file

Tags: c++

I need redirect **the copy** of std::cout to the file. I.e. I need see the output in console, and in file. If I use this:

```
// redirecting cout's output
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  streambuf *psbuf, *backup;
  ofstream filestr;
  filestr.open ("c:\\temp\\test.txt");

  backup = cout.rdbuf();     // back up cout's streambuf

  psbuf = filestr.rdbuf();   // get file's streambuf
  cout.rdbuf(psbuf);         // assign streambuf to cout

  cout << "This is written to the file";

  cout.rdbuf(backup);        // restore cout's original streambuf

  filestr.close();

  return 0;
}
```

then I write string to the file, but I see the nothing in console. How can I do it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and perhaps more appropriate) to do this externally, using `tee` or similar: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee

Comment: @NPE: That assumes this process is running in a context where that's viable.  Which isn't always the case.

Comment: @NPE when someone asks about C++ `iostreams` you answer with a UNIX-specific C function?

Comment: I use the Windows OS now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest you can do is create an output stream class that does this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class my_ostream
{
public:
  my_ostream() : my_fstream("some_file.txt") {}; // check if opening file succeeded!!
  // for regular output of variables and stuff
  template<typename T> my_ostream& operator<<(const T& something)
  {
    std::cout << something;
    my_fstream << something;
    return *this;
  }
  // for manipulators like std::endl
  typedef std::ostream& (*stream_function)(std::ostream&);
  my_ostream& operator<<(stream_function func)
  {
    func(std::cout);
    func(my_fstream);
    return *this;
  }
private:
  std::ofstream my_fstream;
};
```

See this ideone link for this code in action: http://ideone.com/T5Cy1M
I can't currently check if the file output is done correctly though it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `boost::iostreams::tee_device`. See [C++ "hello world" Boost tee example program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999120/c-hello-world-boost-tee-example-program) for an example.

Comment: I try to use your code in Visual Studio, but this IDE doesn't know such headers. :(

Comment: @Bush you need to install and set up `boost` (see www.boost.org), or use a method that doesn't require boost.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, because it is the `streambuf` that determines where the output written to a stream end up, not the stream itself.

C++ does not have any streams or streambufs that support directing the output to multiple destinations, but you could write one yourself.

Comment: >Your code does not work, because it is the streambuf that determines where the output written to a stream end up, not the stream itself.
***
No, this code works fine on Windows. I have got it from the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/ page.

Comment: @Bush: It does not work in the sense that it does not do what you would like it to do.