# Copy all std::cout messages to log file?

Tags: c++, c++11, io, std, cout

I would like to see a log file that will contain exactly the same data as the `std::cout` prints to console (without hiding output), so anything displayed in windows console/linux terminal will be copied to file `output.log`, without using OS-specific tools (like operator `>` in bash or `tee`).

The only one solution i see is to create class that will "cache" messages storing them temporarily in `stringstream` and then "flush" it to both (or more) streams, but this has disadvantage for my case and not suitable because i need my `<<` calls to output `cout` exactly at the moment of their execution.

Is this possible? I don't see anything in standard library suitable for this task.

Comment: Have you already had a look at `std::streambuf` and `std::cout.rdbuf`? You can make your own implementation of `std::streambuf` and then redirect `std::cout` to that.

Comment: You could create a subclass of `std::ostream` that overrides the `operator <<` to redirect the input to both `cout` and whatever other file - no need to worry about buffering/flushing.

Comment: Method from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14155788/3367446 suits my needs. Didn't find it unfortunately then was searching solution before asking.

Comment: @P0W: note that the solution you pointed at is actually pretty bad. In particular, it doesn't allow replication of `std::cout`'s output from components which can't be changed. A much better approach is to use a replicating stream buffer as is shown by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12443391/1120273) answer.