# Why is there no way to display output/input on the console and at the same write it to a file?

Tags: c++, user-input

I know that (in C++) there are several methods which allow the redirection of the output/input to a file and which also allow it to be displayed at the console. However, as far as I am aware, there is no way to do both simultaneously. I haven't found any existing library functions for this purpose. Looking at all of the questions on this topic, a function like this seems to be useful. But why is this task virtually impossible? What are the processes going on in the background?

Comment: you can write a function that writes its argument to a file and to the stdout. Why do you think it is impossible?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number as far as the functions that I have seen, none of them allow this to be accomplished at the same time.

Comment: "Virtually impossible"? A tee stream is minimally writable in a dozen-ish lines of code; searching for "c++ write to file and console" provides a fair amount of ideas (including existing implementations).

Comment: For what its worth Boost has [`boost::iostreams::tee`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/tee.html) which operates like linux's `tee` which can write to both cout and a file. Here's an example of usage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999120/c-hello-world-boost-tee-example-program

Comment: You may have to do one then the other.  Although you may be able to use DMA to transfer data to the file while writing to the console.

Answer (score 2):

It is not impossible to do this. You can output *quasi*-simultaneously to the console and to another stream, e.g. a filestream.

Confer to the documentation of [ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) and [cout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), look at the examples at the bottom of the pages.

You would need to call the corresponding functions (i.e. `cout` or `write`) after each other at a point in your code, where you would like to have them.

Since those would be executed in sequence (and not really simultaneously) you would have to wait until one of those functions returned. (For lengthy outputs it might take a while).
In order to achieve a higher level of parallelization you might consider [multi-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)) techniques. For example, having one [thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) writing the data to console and another writing to a file. But make sure to avoid [data-races](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Data_race), e.g. by duplicating the data or using constructs like [lock_guards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), [mutexes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), [condition variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), [atomics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), or [semaphores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore).