# dupplicating std::ofstream appended content

Tags: c++, std, ofstream

I am using a std::ofstream for trace output.

For some reasons, I sometimes want to dupplicate what I have appended at the end of the std::ofstream (that is not flushed or closed yet), into another std::ofstream;

Do you think of any way of achieving this ?

Thx

Comment: For the moment I am reconsidering my problem. I use temporary std::stringstream, which I append to ofstream or dupplicate them according to the needs. It can do the job.

Comment: yep, I thought about this. I was just going to write it (: But I wonder if there's a better way and give up answering :D +1

Comment: I tried, but rdbuf is not settable for ofstream; I wasn't so sure it would work anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Tee](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) filter from [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) can split an output stream into two.

Here's an example inspired heavily by the one given by [Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509) in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670465).

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/tee.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace io = boost::iostreams;
    typedef io::tee_device<std::ostream, std::stringstream> TeeDevice;
    typedef io::stream<TeeDevice> TeeStream;
    std::stringstream ss;
    TeeDevice teeDevice(std::cout, ss);
    TeeStream tee(teeDevice);
    tee << "Hello World\n" << std::flush;
    std::cout << "ss: " << ss.str() << "\n";
}
```

When I omit the flush manipulator, `ss.str()` returns an empty string. I don't know whether or not this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: yes, the behavior of the stringstream is expected. `stringstream` is [buffered](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) and the buffer is written after [`flush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/). `endl` flushes the stream, too.