# C++ boost::iostreams::tee_device progress bar issue with printing to both ostream and ofstream

Tags: c++, boost, cout, ofstream, ostream

I'm using the Boost Tee_device class to output Text to both **cout** and a **ofstream**. Using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670508/839501). Only difference is that my typedef for TeeDevice looks like this.

```cpp
typedef io::tee_device<ostream, ofstream> TeeDevice;
typedef io::stream< TeeDevice > TeeStream;
```

That part works great.

My problem comes when trying to write a progress bar using the stream object. I'm using `'\r'` to send the courser back to the beginning of the line.

Here's what the code I'm using looks like,

```cpp
//Some code that inits TeeStream* Tee_streamObj;

(*Tee_streamObj) << "Progress:"<< "\n" <<std::flush();

for(int x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
{
   (*Tee_streamObj) << '\r' << (x*100)/100<<"%"<<std::flush();
}

(*Tee_streamObj) << '\r' << "Complete!"<<std::flush();
```

In cout I get 2 lines, the second line keeps getting overwritten and finally looking just like this.

> Progress:
>   Complete! //<-- line keeps getting overwritten as desired

but the file generated from the ofstream looks like this,

> Progress:
>   0%
>   1%
>   2%
>
> ...
>
> 99%
>   100%
>   Complete!

Is there a way to overwrite the last line written to an ofstream in boosts Tee_device class?

I'm using version 1.40 of the boost library and should note that I don't have any control over using a different version.

Ideas?

Thanks ahead of time.

Edit:
I've been playing around with making the ofstream into a fstream. Is there a way to accomplish something like this using seekg or tellg?

Comment: Why are you trying to output a progress bar (a device for indicating progress to a human reader) to a text file?  The overall problem is that "carriage return" is a concept for terminals (or printers), and doesn't apply to files in the same way.

Comment: @DaveS Can you suggest something that might work for files in a similar way? Also I wouldn't be against splitting the process bar functionality if need be to get it to look consistent.

Comment: @DaveS I'm printing it to a text file to keep a record of what the users were displayed. This allows the user to read the output without being forced to redirecting it to a file and then view it from there. The reasoning is so it doesn't disturb their usual work flow if there are no errors. But if there are errors they have a way of communicating it to a coder even if they didn't save the output in the command prompt.