# Is it possible to use insertion operator on two objects at same time?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, fstream, cout, istream

For example if i want to use extraction operator on two object to send the same data tto two object for syntax shortcut

```
(out_file,  cout) << "\n\nTotal tokens found: " << statistics[0] << "\n\nAlphaNumeric Tokens: " << statistics[1]
                << "\n\nPunctuation character found: " << statistics[2] << "\nNumber of whitespace: " << statistics[3]
                << "\nNumber of newlines: " << statistics[4] << "\n\nTokens are stored in out file\n\nPress Enter to exit....";
```

So then the data is applied to out_file and cout at same time?
out_file is fstream..

Comment: Take a look at Boost's tee operator.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670465/using-boostiostreamstee-device

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to a pair of streams using using a [`boost::iostreams::tee_device`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/tee.html).

### teeing.cpp

```
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/tee.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::iostreams::tee_device<std::ostream, std::ostream> Tee;
    typedef boost::iostreams::stream<Tee> TeeStream;

    std::ofstream out_file("./out_file.log");
    Tee tee(std::cout, out_file);

    TeeStream both(tee);

    both << "This is a test!" << std::endl;
}
```

### Build:

```
> clang++ -I/path/to/boost/1.54.0/include teeing.cpp -o teeing
```

### Run:

```
> ./teeing
This is a test!
```

### Verify:

```
> cat ./out_file.log 
This is a test!
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately cout doesn't return ostream object, which contains all your output information. And you can't copy ostream object, which std::operator<< returns.

What you can is to create a function or an object, which combines all you output information and call this function as many times as you wish:

```
void myPrint(std::ostream& os){
  os << "AA" << "BB" << "CC" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  myPrint(cout);
  myPrint(file_out);
  myPrint(cerr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the tee stream filter from boost

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html

It is a template device that does exactly that.. You can also read this article that basically shows how to build one quickly:
http://wordaligned.org/articles/cpp-streambufs

Comment: You don't actually need to use a filter here.